# Implementation of displaying breadcrumb path in ember with sample code or may be direct me to some repository

Tags: ember.js, breadcrumbs

Can some one redirect me to some project code or some working example of displaying crumble path in ember?

This code doesn't work for some reason.

```
    ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
needs: ['breadcrumbs'],
hashChangeOccured: function(context) {
    var loc = context.split('/');
    var path = [];
    var prev;
    loc.forEach(function(it) {
        if (typeof prev === 'undefined') prev = it;
        else prev += ('/'+it)
        path.push(Em.Object.create({ href: prev, name: it }));
    });
    this.get('controllers.breadcrumbs').set('content',path)
}
    });
    ready : function() {
$(window).on('hashchange',function() {
    Ember.Instrumentation.instrument("hash.changeOccured", location.hash);
});
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
   }   

  App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    Ember.Instrumentation.subscribe("hash.changeOccured", {
        before: function(name, timestamp, payload) {
            controller.send('hashChangeOccured', payload);
        },
        after: function() {}
    });
}
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a starting point:

```
APP.Breadcrumb = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['breadcrumb'],
  tagName: 'ul',

  activeChanged: function () {
    var self = this;
    Em.run.next(this, function () {
        self.set('active', self.get('childViews.firstObject.active'));
    });
  }.observes('childViews.firstObject.active'),

  disabled: function () {
    var role = this.get('role');
    if (!Em.isEmpty(role)) {
        return !this.get('controller.controllers.login').hasRole(role);
    }
    return false;
  }.property("controller.controllers.login.authenticationMediator.roles.@each"),

  currentPathChanged: function() {
    this.rerender();
  }.observes('controller.currentPath'),

  template: function () {
    var template = [],
        controller = this.get('controller'),
        router = controller.container.lookup('router:main'),
        currentHandlerInfos = router.get('router.currentHandlerInfos');

    for (var i = 0; i < currentHandlerInfos.length; i++) {
        var name = Em.get(currentHandlerInfos[i], 'name');

        if (!(router.hasRoute(name) || router.hasRoute(name + '.index')) || name.endsWith('.index')) {
            continue;
        }

        var notLast = i < currentHandlerInfos.length - 1 && !Em.get(currentHandlerInfos[i + 1], 'name').endsWith('.index');

        template.push('<li' + (notLast ? '>' : ' class="active">'));
        if (notLast) {
            template.push('{{#linkTo "' + name + '"}}');
        }
        template.push(name);
        if (notLast) {
            template.push('{{/linkTo}}');
        }

        if (notLast) {
            template.push('<span class="divider">/</span>');
        }

        template.push('</li>');
    }

    return Em.Handlebars.compile(template.join("\n"));
  }.property('controller.currentPath')  
});
```

Comment: Can you please post complete code for template, views, route and controllers? Sorry, i am noob to ember.

Comment: if (!(router.hasRoute(name) || router.hasRoute(name + '.index')) || name.endsWith('.index')) {

Comment: At that line it states that object has no method like "endswith()"

Comment: if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function (suffix) {
        return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    };
}